# Change Playback Device Of An Existing AudioSession

Tags: c#, naudio

I am trying to change the playback device of the existing audio sessions on my devices.

I know that this is possible.

At the moment I use naudio library to access WASAPI functions.

I believe the way I should go towards is here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756610(v=vs.85).aspx

But after a quick read I didn't find how to change the streams, only how to get notifications from them.

Any further help would be very much appreciated. 
At least a pointer to the right class? or function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you've done so far?

Comment: At the moment i have gained access to the playbackand record devices through the MMDeviceEnumerator where i can access each device's sessions and manipulate their volume/mute state and get their icons. I cannot change their playback device id or something else through that, neither from the device object MMDevice i can pass to other device a session. I assume so far that this approach is incorrect.